# How do I write to file every 20 seconds

Tags: objective-c

How would I make this code write the latitude/longitude to file every 20 seconds? Thank you.

```
// Save the longitude & latitude to file & check for errors
NSString *newLocString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%s%f\n%s%f","Lat=",currentLocation.coordinate.latitude,"Long=",currentLocation.coordinate.longitude];

NSString *path = @"var/Coordinates/myLocation.txt";
NSError *error = nil;

BOOL success = [newLocString writeToFile:path atomically:YES encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&error];
NSString *status = success ? @"Success" : @"Failure";
if(success){

    UIAlertView *savedAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Success!"message:@"The myLocation.txt file was updated." delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [savedAlert show];

    NSLog(@"Done Writing: %@",status);
}
else{
    NSLog(@"Done Writing: %@",status);
    NSLog(@"Error: %@",[error localizedDescription]);
}
```

Comment: Is this for an NSA app?

Comment: Strange question! No

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use an `NSTimer` which fires every 20 seconds:

```
NSTimer *timer = [NSTimer timerWithTimeInterval:20
                                         target:self
                                       selector:@selector( yourFunctionThatWritesToFile )
                                       userInfo:nil
                                        repeats:YES];
[timer fire];
```

Comment: Thank you, would it be possible for you to show me how to add this into my code?

Comment: Move the code you wrote in the question to a function. Then replace 'yourFunctionThatWritesToFile' with the name of your function. You'll have a property which holds the users current location, which you update in the `CLLocationManager` delegate, which gives you the users location. I won't write the code for you, that's your job if you want to learn.

Comment: I made the function void printFile(CLLocation *currentLocation), replaced where function was with "printFile (currentLocation);"& it works. Then I add under my function call this: NSTimer *timer = [NSTimer timerWithTimeInterval:20 target:self selector:printFile(currentLocation) userInfo:nil repeats:YES]; but get error "sending void to parameter of incompatible type SEL.?

Comment: Now I change to this: NSTimer *timer = [NSTimer timerWithTimeInterval:20 target:self selector:@selector(printFile) userInfo:nil repeats:YES]; I now get warning "Undeclared selector 'printFile'.

Comment: Read my comment again, CAREFULLY.  "You'll have a property which holds the users current location". So your function should be `- (void)printCurrentLocation` and your selector `@selector(printCurrentLocation)`. You won't be passing current location as a parameter, it will be a property, so you access it with `self.currentLocation`.

Comment: Ok, thanks for your help, but I can't get it working, I know I must learn more basics before asking here. If I use - (void)printCurrentLocation Xcode then gives me error, "use of undeclared identifier 'currentLocation' in my NSString *newLocString line. I'm completely confused.

Comment: I will keep your answer, maybe I can understand it at a later date.

Comment: Please READ the WHOLE comment. I said `You'll have a property which holds the users current location`. And I also said `you access it with self.currentLocation`. If you don't know what a `property` is, you really shouldn't be doing this and instead starting with the very basics of Objective-C.